# How can I set an "hierarchized conditional formatting" in Excel 2010?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I need to set a "hierarchical conditional formatting" in Excel 2010, based in to inputs: the format of the left cell and if the value belongs or not to a range.

To understand what I need, suppose that I am in the cell B1.

Then, i was able to set the first condition by clicking in "Use a formula do determine which cells to format" and typing =CELL("format";A1)="P1" , since I need to know if A1 is or not a percentage.

Also, I am able to set the second condition by clicking in "Format only cells that contain" and then in "between", for example, 0.5 and 0.6.

The problem is that the desired range depends of the format of the cell at left. So, I wanted to set something like that:

If (A1 is percentage) AND (B1 is between 0.5 and 0.6) then apply the selected format.

If (A1 is not percentage) AND (B1 is between 5 and 6) then apply the selected format.

I tried to select "Use a formula do determine which cells to format" and type the formula below but it didn't work!

= AND(CELL("format";A1)="P1" ; AND("B1 > 0.5"; "B1 < 0.6"))

Can anyone help me?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quotes are incorrect:

```
= AND(CELL("format";A1)="P1" ; B1 >= 0.5; B1 <= 0.6)
```

and the second:

```
= AND(CELL("format";A1)<>"P1" ; B1 >= 5; B1 <= 6)
```

If you have the same format you can combine:

```
=OR(AND(CELL("format";A1)="P1" ; B1 >= 0.5; B1 <= 0.6);AND(CELL("format";A1)<>"P1" ; B1 >= 5; B1 <= 6))
```